# How to transform data to binary when the value is above the column median (1, else 0)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

For all the columns in a pandas DataFrame, I want to transform the value into the following kind of code:

```
for col in list(df_sample.columns):
    for val in col:
        if val > df_sample.col.median():
            val=1
        else:
            val=0
```

When the value is above the column median, then 1 else 0. Maybe new columns of median columns are needed first to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a decent one liner

```
(dat > dat.median()).astype('int')
```

This calculates the median of each column and compares it to the values in the column, finally converting the bool values to an integer.

This returns

```
Out[23]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  0
2  0  1
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  1  1
```

**data**

```
np.random.seed(1234)
dat = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.arange(6), 'b': np.random.randn(6)})
```

The dataset constructed above is

```
dat
Out[24]: 
   a         b
0  0  0.471435
1  1 -1.190976
2  2  1.432707
3  3 -0.312652
4  4 -0.720589
5  5  0.887163
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>df[col].mean() else 0)
```

Also you can do:

```
df.where(df>df.mean(),0).mask(df>df.mean(),1)
```