# How to transform dataframe to binary based on values being above/below the row median (if > median, 1, else 0)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to transform a dataframe to binary based on row median. Please see my input and expected output below.

```
import pandas as pd
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'row1': [5, 10, 20], 'row2': [1, 30, 40],},
                        index = ['2021-02-24', '2021-02-25', '2021-02-26'])
df_expected_output = pd.DataFrame({'row1': [1, 0, 0], 'row2': [0, 1, 1],},
                        index = ['2021-02-24', '2021-02-25', '2021-02-26'])
df_median = df_input.median(axis=1)
```

I found this [elegant solution for transforming based on column median here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650047/how-to-transform-data-to-binary-when-the-value-is-above-the-column-median-1-el) but could not get it to work for comparing rows.

```
(dat > dat.median()).astype('int')
```

How can I do this for rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with the correct axis:

```
df_input.gt(df_input.median(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
```

output:

```
            row1  row2
2021-02-24     1     0
2021-02-25     0     1
2021-02-26     0     1
```